How to Accurately Implement Fractional Daily Interest in Solidity
I'm trying to implement a daily interest rate calculation in Solidity based on an annual interest rate, but I'm facing issues with the precision of fractional numbers. Here's the calculation I'm using:
uint256 private constant ANNUAL_INTEREST_SCALE = 1e9;
uint256 private constant ANNUAL_INTEREST_PERCENT = 2;
uint256 public constant DAILY_INTEREST_RATE = (ANNUAL_INTEREST_PERCENT * ANNUAL_INTEREST_SCALE) / 365;

Given the constants above, the daily interest rate I calculated is 5479452 when scaled by 1e9. However, when I want to apply this rate to calculate rewards, it seems too high because Solidity does not handle fractional numbers. The real value I'm aiming which is 2/365 = 0.005479452.


Lets say one day 2% annual interest calculated without solidity is:
1 day interest = 2 / 365 = 0.005479452

And 1 day interest in solidity is: 5479452

Lets say reward formula is:
rewardTokens for 1 day is = 5479452 * depsositAmount = 5479452 * 1 Token = 5479452


Solution:
so reward is 5479452 which is usually in Wei in remix, we can convert into Gwei via web3.js which will be equal to 0.005479452 Gwei.


Show the code used to calculate the rewards. When using fixed point arithmetic you have to be careful about the operation order.

correct @Ismael

@Ismael could you please check mine answer on it that i finally got ?

I still don't understand what was your problem. In fixed point arithmetic number are multiplied by a large scale factor (10^9 in your case). To get the real value they have to divided by the same factor. This is usually calculated in the UI code.

Yess correct @Ismael


Lets say one day 2% annual interest calculated without solidity is:
1 day interest = 2 / 365 = 0.005479452

And 1 day interest in solidity is: 5479452

Lets say reward formula is:
rewardTokens for 1 day is = 5479452 * depsositAmount = 5479452 * 1 Token = 5479452


Solution:
so reward is 5479452 which is usually in Wei in remix, we can convert into Gwei via web3.js which will be equal to 0.005479452 Gwei.

